# Python - isinstance() not working as I'd expect

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class called Route (with its own __repr__() function), and an instance of a Route called default_route.  However, if I call isinstance(default_route,Route), it unexpectedly returns False, viz:

```
[Dbg]>>> default_route
Route(office(235)=323-654-3242)
[Dbg]>>> isinstance(default_route,Route)
False
[Dbg]>>> default_route.__class__
<class 'route.Route'>
[Dbg]>>> Route
<class 'route.Route'>
[Dbg]>>> type(default_route)
<class 'route.Route'>
[Dbg]>>> type(default_route) is Route
False
```

The class definition is really straightforward and uncomplicated:

```
class Route(object):
    def __init__(self, phone, condition=None):
        self.phone=phone
        self.condition=condition
        self.choice_name=None
```

I'm just baffled by this; why would isinstance() not return True above?

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue, what version of python are you running? Can you share the class definition?

Comment: create [mcve] please - what is Route?

Comment: Could you please share the actual class definition ? I tested with other names but for me it says `True`

Comment: Can you try doing `Route is type(default_root)` and give us the result?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: Note: Since the code is Python 2, old-style classes may be involved. `Route is type(default_root)` won't work if `Route` is an old-style class; `type` just returns `instance` on instances of old-style classes, not the class itself. Directly accessing `__class__` is more reliable (though it is *possible* to shadow the `__class__`, no sane code should ever do so).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I forgot we were in Python2... Ok, please show us the class definition!

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward class definition:class Route(object):
        def __init__(self, phone, condition=None):
            self.phone=phone
            self.condition=condition
            self.choice_name=None

Answer (score 16):

This could easily happen if you did the following:

1. `import route` and create `default_route` using `route.Route`
2. Invoke `reload(route)` to pull in some code changes to the module (or just for fun; doesn't matter if the module is unchanged, `reload` will still reload it)

You could encounter this in a similar way if `default_route` was also defined in `route`, and you did `from route import Route`, then `reload`-ed `route`, then did `from route import default_route` (order of importing `Route` and `default_route` is irrelevant, as long as a `reload` occurred between them, and the older one was not reimported). Either way, you have an instance and a class from subtly different versions of the module; they might look the same, have the same behaviors, etc., but they are not the same module, and therefore not the same classes, instances, etc.

In either case, a quick check would be to invoke `default_route.__class__ is Route`; if that evaluates to `True`, it's possible you've got some weird `ABC` based class with [a broken `__subclasshook__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__), but more likely it will evaluate to `False`, indicating that the two classes, despite the matching name, actually originate from independent loads of the module.

Comment: I think the chance OP used reload without noticing are... slim. I think the subclass hook is what we should investigate.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: Using `reload` without noticing: Hard. Not understanding the implications of `reload` and omitting it from the question as "irrelevant"? Easy. One of the *extremely* common errors made while developing a module "live" in every introductory Python course I've ever participated in or taught has been making an instance of a class, `reload`ing the module it came from, then wondering why the changes to the module don't seem to have applied, or why newly created instances don't work properly with the old instance (often due to `isinstance` checks in operator overloads).

Comment: I think having two slightly different versions of the same module loaded was  likely in my case; During debugging, I would often make changes and reload the route module, but if that module was also imported (and cached) in some other module, it is likely that this then resulted in two different versions of the module being loaded in the debugger at the same time, and causing the seemingly impossible situation above.

Comment: @W.Sadkin: Yeah, fixing indirect imports is difficult. If you're using `ipython`, you can [enable automatic reloading](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) (which rechecks modules for changes on every prompt and reloads them seamlessly), or manually use [the `deepreload` function it provides](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.deepreload.html#module-IPython.lib.deepreload) (possibly replacing `reload` so you never forget) to simplify. Won't help for objects created from reloaded classes, but simplifies reloading a lot.

Comment: Since this is Python 2, you'd need the `ipython` API pre-6.0 (6.0 dropped Python 2 support), where `deepreload` is named `dreload`, but the use is pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this was a problem with the debugger I was using (Pythonwin); no matter how many times I reloaded and re-ran my code in that instance of the debugger, the problem was completely steady-state, and, as since I was in the process of debugging my code, I was stumped as to what to do next.  However, given some of the comments above about reloading, I started to suspect something might be wrong with the debugging environment itself, so I closed the program, reopened it, and suddenly the problem was no longer reproducible.

Sorry to have bothered everyone, but at least if someone sees the same problem, maybe this will make them realize they're not crazy, and that Python itself isn't broken in some subtle way!

Comment: Maybe since the problem is no longer reproducible and the solution (albeit not understood) was found, you could mark this as the correct answer so that it is the first one we see.